# How to convert string field into integer field in kibana

Tags: kibana, elastic-stack, metricbeat, event-id

So i am sending data of event viewer through winlogbeat to kibana. Actually my event_data.boottime value is coming in string format and i wanted this data field in number format. I have tried changing the format in winlogbeat.template.json but its not working.[boot time field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C15wR.png)

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure the mapping is defined correctly so that the data is automatically converted and save in required format by elastic.

```
"boot_time": {
    "type": "long"
}
```

You can check the current mapping of your type by using

```
http://elasticip:port/indexname/typename/_mapping
```